# How do I declare inline functions in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have used the inline functions in Objective-C, but I can't use the same syntax in Swift. This is how I did it in Objective-C.

```
    static inline CGRect CGRectMultiply(CGRect rect, CGFloat factor)
{
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*factor, rect.origin.y*factor, rect.size.width*factor, rect.size.height*factor);
}
```

This is how I call this,

```
fromRect = CGRectMultiply(rect, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

Even the `CGRect` has inline functions like `CGRectMake` in Swift, but I can't find the syntax for creating one here. I tried this one in Swift, but cannot use this as a inline function like `CGRectMake`

```
   extension CGRect {
    func CGRectMultiply(factor: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: origin.x*factor, y: origin.y*factor, width: size.width*factor, height: size.height*factor)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your extension looks fine. What you mean you can't use it? let myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10).CGRectMultiply(2)   //{x 0 y 0 w 20 h 20}

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus but, thats not how we call a inline function, right? We call the CGRectMake function directly, but this CGRectMultiply function I created, requires a CGRect object.

Comment: That's how you call the extension you need a CGRect to multiply (self)

Comment: fromRect = rect.CGRectMultiply(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)